# SSN returns "no match found"

Tags: united-states, texas, immigration

I have an offer from an employer in Texas, everything turned out okay except when they look up for my SSN, they said it turns out as "no match found"

A little backstory:

I'm a Mexican Citizen, came to the states for college, legally(fees, visas, tests), graduated in 2013 and applied for an OPT permit, which allows me to work in the US for a year. When I received my OPT card I went ahead and asked for a SSN at the SSA office, when I get there and give my information, turns out I've had a SSN since 1990(I was a year old) I'm not sure why I had one but afterwards I asked my family and said one of my uncles got it for me(still not sure why). At the SSA Office they told me I would keep this number since it was already associated to my name. So on May 2014 I got my SSN Card. The OPT card expired on Jan 21, 2015 and that was the date I returned to Mexico, turned my I-96 form(I think its I-96 or I-94, it's the permit for entrance to the country) and got my Student Visa voided and I've been living in Mexico ever since.

Now I have applied for a job in Texas and well the rest is explained in the first sentence, employer asked to look and see if I have a DHS authorization for this SSN, I have all my paperwork saved(even envelopes) but I can't stop thinking that someone might've thrown something out, or that I never got an authorization letter for this number. I can't avoid panicking a bit, so I wanted to ask what should I do in the case that I don't find this DHS authorization.

PS: The SSN card says *VALID FOR WORK ONLY WITH DHS AUTHORIZATION*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like it belongs on https://workplace.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Well I'm a member of workplace, but since its more law than a workplace environment issue, I thought it would be a better fit in this site @JasonAller

Comment: I read the question as presented as asking what should be done if you can't find the DHS authorization. Asked at workplace it can be a procedural question, asked here it feels like it is seeking legal advice which is a closure reason.

Comment: Mmmm when you say it that way, it does make sense... @JasonAller

Comment: Given that your OPT has expired, why would you be authorized to work in the US?  Have you received some other form of work authorization?

Comment: So the SSN is not valid anymore? What do I need to do to make it valid @NateEldredge I'm barely on the background check and drug screening part of the hiring process

Comment: I assume the SSN is valid, but just having an SSN doesn't necessarily mean you are authorized to work in the US.  You may have to apply for a work visa.  This is not a quick or simple matter; you or your employer would probably want to hire an immigration lawyer.

Comment: Oh well I am going to get a visa, but i need a signed contract before applying for it(the process is quite straight forward and quick for the work visa i would be getting) but when they were doing the background check thats when the SSN turned out as no match my thoughts are that they used a different name than the one I have in my SSN card but they havent confirmed anything yet. @NateEldredge (the application picked up my Second Last name, whereas the SSN card doesnt have it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand why a potential employer in the US would be asking for your SSN or looking up anything relating to your SSN at this stage at all. A foreigner is not in general expected to have an SSN. You happen to have an SSN because you were authorized to work in the US in the past, but that's a special case. Most Mexicans don't have an SSN.

In order to hire a foreigner like you, the company would have to sponsor you for some kind of visa that allows you to work for them in the US. (Or, since you are Mexican, for certain jobs you could get a TN visa based on the company's offer letter.) In the usual case of a foreigner without an SSN, he/she would only be able to get an SSN after entering the US with that visa, so it doesn't make sense for them to expect anything from your SSN at this point. In any case, you do not have work authorization in the US until you enter the US with a visa status that allows work authorization, so it doesn't make sense that you say they are trying to "look and see if you have a DHS authorization" before hiring you. Perhaps you mistakenly indicated to them that you already have work authorization and don't need sponsorship?

Comment: **Yes!** I just had a talk this morning with the HR rep that's handling my case, I think she didn't know I was a foreigner until I told her yesterday. After I explained to her my situation she just replied *"I think it will be fine when you have your authorization card"* I think that was the whole issue; the rep didn't know about my nationality.